# Pass a async function as a callback parameter?

Tags: python, asynchronous, lambda

I need to pass a callback to a constructor:

```
class SomeClass:
    data_receiver: Callable[[bytes], None]

    def __init__(self, data_receiver: Callable[[bytes], None]):
        self.data_receiver = data_receiver  # type:ignore
```

When this callback is invoked, I need it to invoke this async function.

```
async def some_async_function(data: bytes):
    pass
```

How can I pass the function "some_async_function" as the callback, needed for the SomeClass constructor?

Here is what I tried:

```
async def main():
    obj = SomeClass(some_async_function)  # <-- error
    obj.data_receiver(bytes())

asyncio.run(main())
```

The error I am getting is:

> Argument of type "(data: bytes) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, None]" cannot
> be assigned to parameter "data_receiver" of type "(bytes) -> None" in
> function "**init**"   Type "(data: bytes) -> Coroutine[Any, Any,
> None]" cannot be assigned to type "(bytes) -> None"
> Function return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, None]" is incompatible with type "None"
> Type cannot be assigned to type "None"

**EDIT**:

Someone suggested that I should "wrap that in a sync function that calls that async function and resolves it with asyncio.run"

So I tried this:

```
async def main():
    data_receiver: Callable[[bytes], None] = lambda data: asyncio.run(some_async_function(data))
    obj = SomeClass(data_receiver)  # <-- error
    obj.data_receiver(bytes())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Which gives me this error:

> RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Comment: `some_async_function` is supposed to be the callback, or is supposed to be a function that, when called, returns a callback…?

Comment: I think you might've rewritten your code a bit too much and it doesn't reflect your original problem. The error you mentioned should only a type checking issue since a coroutine doesn't match the `Callable[[], None]` type annotation.  How exactly does your original code want the callback and what for?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I rewrote my question. I have no control over the `some_async_function` code. But I need to invoke exactly that function during a callback.

Comment: @deceze `some_async_function` is supposed to be the callback.

Comment: Then you want to wrap that in a sync function that calls that async function and resolves it with `asyncio.run`.

Comment: Then my question is: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Very roughly: `def cb(*args, **kwargs): return asyncio.run(some_async_function(*args, **kwargs))`. And pass `cb` as callback.

Comment: Then I get the `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a callback which adds a call to the async function as a "event loop task"

```
async def main():
    el = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    callback: Callable[[bytes], None] = lambda data: el.create_task(some_async_function(data))
    obj = SomeClass(callback)

asyncio.run(main())
```